# Formatting decimal as currency without code sign and extra static text in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have try:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemPrice, StringFormat='#,##0.00'}" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Demi" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

and yes it shows 4.2 as 4.20 but currently I want to surround the value with some static text for example:-
(+4.20) as adding "(+{price})".

I cannot find the way to format a text within a binding price format on my search engine. Mostly show one kind of stringformat

Comment: Use StringFormat='(+#,##0.00)'

Comment: dunno if this is suits your needs but try this: `Text="{Binding ItemPrice, StringFormat='some example text +({0:N})'}"`

Answer (score 0):

Answering solutions based from comment. Credit to both @Babbillumpa and @XAMIMAX.

Answer 1: `Text="{Binding Path=ItemPrice, StringFormat='(+{0:N})'}"`

Answer 2: `Text="{Binding Path=ItemPrice, StringFormat='(+#,##0.00)'}"`

Both works.